# Playing audio in Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5

I would like to play audio in Qt5.
I am using Qt Creator and I set a slot to play audio.
Actually I have the "QVector datavec;" to be played globally.

My problem is when I try to proc, I got an error message saying;
"QAudioOutput: open error".
I have no clue what kinda error I got and how I can solve it.

Here is my entire function and I hope anyone could have a clue to solve this problem.
Thank you very much in advance.
/* maybe invalid format settings may cause this error? */

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_btnPlay_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<<"play button clicked";

    // format settings
    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(32000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(64);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    // audio output settings
    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    QAudioOutput *audio = new QAudioOutput(info, format);

    // convert to qbyte array
    QByteArray bytearray;
    bytearray=QByteArray::fromRawData((const char *)datavec.constData(), datavec.size() * sizeof(double));

    // audio buffer settings
    QBuffer audioBuffer;
    audioBuffer.setBuffer(&bytearray);
    audioBuffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    // play audio
    audio->start(&audioBuffer); // an error occurs here

    qDebug()<<"playing... done.";
}
```